# Integral to calculate surface area of a right triangular prism

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

$$ \iint_{s}xyzdS  $$ base is a triangle with vertices (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) e (0, 0, 1) and the other base is in plan x + y + z = 4.
How can I evaluate and see the figure? [image: My trying in drawing the figure]

Comment: It may be a bit clearer to say the prism lies within the plane $x+y+z=1$ and $x+y+z=4$. Are you trying to find the surface area of the prism using a surface integral, given by $\displaystyle\iint_SdS$? Or are you computing the particular surface integral $\displaystyle\iint_Sxyz\,dS$? These are the not the same thing.

Comment: computing the particular surface integral

Comment: Are you familiar with parametric surfaces? If not, you could try a change of coordinates $(x,y,z)\mapsto(u,v,w)$ to rotate the prism such that its projection in the $(u,v)$ plane is a triangle with the same dimensions as the base.

Comment: Title says "right prism", so I think this is what you want: https://www.geogebra.org/3d/mv3ffmfs

Comment: Now, how can I solve the surface integral?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

From the right triangle (PA,PC,BC) in the base plane point P appears pushed up to B by 1 unit (PB=GF=1) keeping AE,CD the same. The (CD,AE,BF) are parallel sides extruded by lengths 3 units.

Base triangle is not right angled. The extrusion sides (D,G,P,C) are parallelograms. None of the faces contains a right angle.

[image]

Comment: I tried another way, using the two plan, posted the image below

Answer (score 0):

That's th prism I did, don't know if it is right tho
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEer5.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).